# How to merge and rearrange data from a CSV file using C?

Tags: c, csv, file, merge

I am trying to read information from 2 CSV files: import.txt and ss_data.txt (contents shown below). Import.txt has the data in the following order: employee id, name, address. I want to create a new file containing the social security numbers from ss_data.txt between the employee name and address. I would appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this, the closest I have come is appending the new file after the original.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define BSIZE 12
#define STRSIZE 70
#define MAXEMP 25

typedef struct employee{
    int empID;
    char name[STRSIZE];
    int ssNumber;
    char address[STRSIZE];
} employee;

typedef struct {
    int empID;
    char ssn[BSIZE];
} ssdef;

typedef employee *empPtr;

int main(void)
{
    // Define variables.
    FILE *inFile, *newFile, *outFile;
    char str[STRSIZE];
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;
    
    // new employee
    employee newEmp[MAXEMP];
    ssdef newSS;
    
    // Open files.
    inFile = fopen("import.txt", "r");
    newFile = fopen("ss_data.txt", "r");
    outFile = fopen("updated.txt", "w");
    
    // Check files opened. 
    if(inFile == NULL || newFile == NULL || outFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("Could not open files");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    
    while(fgets(str, STRSIZE, inFile) != NULL)
    {
    memset(&newEmp[index], '\0', sizeof(employee));    
    sscanf(str, "%6u,%[^,],%[^\n\r]", &newEmp[index].empID, newEmp[index].name, newEmp[index].address);
       // printf("%u.%s.%s\n", newEmp[index].empID, newEmp[index].name, newEmp[index].address);
    index++;
    }
    
    while(fgets(str, STRSIZE, newFile) != NULL) 
    {
    memset(&newSS, '\0', sizeof(newSS));    
    str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
    sscanf(str, "%6u%s", &newSS.empID, newSS.ssn);
    //printf("%u.%s\n", newSS.empID, newSS.ssn);

    for(i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        if(newEmp[i].empID == newSS.empID)
        {
            fprintf(outFile,"%u,%s,%s,\"%s\"\n", newEmp[i].empID, newEmp[i].name, newSS.ssn, newEmp[i].address);
            break;
        }
    }
    }   
    printf("Copied");
    
    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(newFile);
    fclose(outFile);
    
    return 0;
}
```

import.txt:

```
289383,Estefana Lewey,9940 Ohio Drv, 85021
930886,Burl Livermore,226 Amherst, 08330
692777,Lannie Crisler,8143 Woods Drv, 20901
636915,Zena Hoke,82 Roehampton St, 47905
747793,Vicente Clevenger,9954 San Carlos St., 55016
238335,Lidia Janes,348 Depot Ave, 29576
885386,Claire Paladino,587 Front Ave, 32703
760492,Leland Stillson,9793 Boston Lane, 08610
516649,Wes Althouse,8597 Annadale Drive, 06514
641421,Nadia Gard,218 George Street, 29150
```

ss_data.txt:

```
289383,591-82-1520
930886,661-18-3839
692777,590-36-6612
636915,510-92-2741
747793,233-46-1002
238335,512-92-7402
885386,376-74-3432
760492,576-55-8588
516649,002-58-0518
641421,048-14-6428
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, post the code you have.

Comment: Posted what I have at the moment. I keep removing things as they don't work.

Comment: there are a couple of things instantly `while(fgets(str, STRSIZE, inFile) != NULL);` has a `;` at the end and shouldn't  (it means there is no loop)

You are double closing file handles which isn't good

Comment: Also have a look at the function `sscanf` this will help you read the lines from the text files

Comment: Thanks, took care of that issue!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how to read from the second file in the loop to get the SS data in the correct location of the new file.

Comment: I would read import.txt and store it in memory, then read through the ssn file after in a new loop and add the ssn's to it. I'd use a struct something like `struct Employee
{
   int employee_id;
   char name[NAME_LEN];
   char address[ADDR_LEN];
   int zip_code;
   char ssn[SSN_LEN];
};`

Comment: This might help you read your data into an array of `struct`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210630/parsing-csv-file-into-structs-using-c. If you read each file into separate arrays, you can then add code to combine the data into the desired result.

Comment: I'll try setting up a structure as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I uploaded the final version of my code based on your advice and some additional help.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output two message, that you need to correct.     
    untitled1.c:50:20: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
       50 |     sscanf(str, "%6u,%[^,],%[^\n\r]", &newEmp[index].empID, newEmp[index].name, newEmp[index].address);

a similar problem on line 59

Comment: OT: regarding; `if(inFile == NULL || newFile == NULL || outFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("Could not open files");
        exit(0);
    }`  this 'grouping' looses the reason for the failure.  Suggest after each call to `fopen()` to check and if the returned value is NULL, then immediately call `perror( "fopen to ... failed" );`  so the user is informed of why the system thinks the function failed.